# An upper bound problem with inverse hyperbolic

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

Need to show that

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \operatorname{sech}(r) < \int_0^n \operatorname{sech}(x) \mathrm{d} x $$
which is done and got to

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \operatorname{sech}(r) < \tan^{-1} \left( \sinh(n) \right) $$

Then we need to find an **upper bound** for the summation.
and that's what I got stuck.

I can only get the "sense" that the graph of $\sinh$ goes to $\infty$,
so that the $\tan^{-1}$ is kinda of at the aysmpote, which is $\pi/2$.

But is there a formal way to see this?

Comment: **Hint :** use the fact that $\mathrm{sech}$ function is decreasing over $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Answer (score 3):

For $\cosh$ is strictly increasing (and positive) over $[0,+\infty)$, $\mathrm{sech} = \frac{1}{\cosh}$ is strictly decreasing over $[0,+\infty)$.
Hence,
$$
\forall k \geqslant 0 \text{ integer}, \quad \int_k^{k+1}\mathrm{sech}(t)dt > \mathrm{sech}(k+1)  \cdot (k+1-k) = \mathrm{sech}(k+1).
$$
To conclude, sum over $k\in [\![0,\ldots,n-1]\!]$.